# How does SAS decide which file to select when using wildcards

Tags: import, sas

I have a SAS code that looks something like this:

```
DATA WORK.MY_IMPORT_&stamp; 
    INFILE "M:\YPATH\myfile_150*.csv"
    delimiter = ';' MISSOVER DSD lrecl = 1000000 firstobs = 2 ignoredoseof;
    [...]
RUN;
```

Now, at M:\YPATH I have several files named myfile_150.YYYYMMDD. The code works the way it is supposed to by importing always the latest file. I am wondering how SAS decides which file to choose, since the wildcard `*` can be replaced by anything. Does it sort the files in descending order and choose the first one?

Comment: "The code works the way it is supposed to by importing always the latest file." That is not what this code would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system, SAS 9.4 TS1M4, SAS is reading ALL files that satisfy the wildcard.

I created 3 files (file_A.csv, file_B.csv, and file_C.csv).  Each contain 1 record ('A', 'B', and 'C' respectively).

```
data test;
infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv"
    delimiter = ';' MISSOVER DSD lrecl = 1000000 ignoredoseof;
format char $1.;
input char $;
run;
```

(Note I dropped the `firstobs` option from your code.)

The resulting `TEST` data set contains 3 observations, 'A', 'B', and 'C'.

This is the order of files returned when issuing

```
dir c:\temp\file_*.csv
```

SAS is using the default behavior of the OS and reading the files in that order.

```
25   data test;
26   infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv"
27       delimiter = ';' MISSOVER DSD lrecl = 1000000 ignoredoseof;
28   format char $1.;
29   input char $;
30   run;

NOTE: The infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv" is:
      Filename=c:\temp\file_A.csv,
      File List=c:\temp\file_*.csv,RECFM=V,
      LRECL=1000000

NOTE: The infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv" is:
      Filename=c:\temp\file_B.csv,
      File List=c:\temp\file_*.csv,RECFM=V,
      LRECL=1000000

NOTE: The infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv" is:
      Filename=c:\temp\file_C.csv,
      File List=c:\temp\file_*.csv,RECFM=V,
      LRECL=1000000

NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv".
      The minimum record length was 1.
      The maximum record length was 1.
NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv".
      The minimum record length was 1.
      The maximum record length was 1.
NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "c:\temp\file_*.csv".
      The minimum record length was 1.
      The maximum record length was 1.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 3 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: You're right, my bad. It actually does read in all of them. I inherited the code and the update_date in the output dataset is changed later on to the date of the latest file, that's what got me confused.